# Hibernate: how to mirror specific data

Tags: database, hibernate, replication, hibernate-envers, auditing

I'm currently working on a project using hibernate for persistance on top of databases of various types.
The solution consists of multiple servers with their own databases.
The challenge is now to build server that receives all data from all other servers to provide monitoring and reporting functionality. If data changes in one of the servers, it shall (almost) instantly be sent to the monitoring server. Network latency and outage shall be handled.

I found two possible ways to monitor the data changes (insert, update, delete):

**Hibernate Envers**

Appears to be an auditing solution that builds a protocol of all modifications in individually created database tables. I could not find information how to filter the data. This may become necessary in the future

**Hibernate Interceptor**

The interceptor functionality (e.g. described in the [Mykong blog entry](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/)). It 
does almost the same like Envers but gives me the possibility to use my own audit table to store the modifications and to filter the data by my own criteria if necessary

My idea is now to

- store the modifications by serializing the data to the audit table
- scan the table (e.g. every 30 seconds) for new entries
- transfer the entries (e.g. by http upload) to the monitoring server
- import the data to the monitoring database using hibernate

My question is now:
Is there a better or easier way to solve this?

Comment: You could choose Envers for their good data gathering, but data retrieval via Envers API could be pain, even when you just want filter it. Be careful. If the interceptor solution is enough for you I would go with it, because you keep control in your hands. Did you look into some database level solution?